# Populate InventoryID while searching for cross reference alternate ID

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to select inventory using 'UsrAlternateIDs' (custom field) value (which are concatenation of cross reference value of stock items). This is where I am trying to implement.
[image]

So, if I type in correct InventoryID, it would select me the inventory which exists now. But now, whatever value I type, first it would check if it is the correct inventoryID and select inventory for me. if not it should look for alternateids of inventory item and if I type whichever (separated from ';') it should select inventory item for me.

Here is the code snippet I have written:

```
protected void FSAppointmentDetPart_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
      
      var row = (FSAppointmentDetPart)e.Row;
      if(row==null) return;
      InventoryItem item = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<row.InventoryID>>;
      if(item!=null)
      {
         InventoryItem itm = PXSelect<Inventory, Whenre<InventoryItem.alternateIDs, Contains<row.InventoryID>>;
         if(itm!=null)
         {
           
         }
         else
         {
           throw new PXException("Invalid Inventory Item");
          }
      }
      //sender.SetValue<ContactExt.usrCreditRecordVerified>(e.Row, false);
}
```

But it is not working. What I am I missing?

Besides, I also looked into the Business logic of the page 'Purchase Orders' which would look for column AlternateIDs and work if is not concatenated and only single value. But the code doesn't make much sense to me. It would be great if you could explain that to me.

Thank you.

Comment: are you trying to make the selector search for alternate id and the inventory id?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but this is what I am trying to do.
But this is what I am trying to do.

https://www.screencast.com/t/gnF8W2jggSZ

The only problem here is, if the field value is '12345678; 23456798', then it doesn't work for either '12345678' or '23456798'. Because, these values come from concatenation of cross-references of inventory item.

Comment: Did you check my answer? and try to use that attribute, this attribute from acumatica should do that, so you dont want to use a user defined field with the concatenated alternateID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make your selector search for both inventory id and the alternate id, consider using the

> CrossItemAttribute

Sample usage can be like this, here INPrimaryAlternateType.CPN defines the type of alternate id.

```
#region InventoryID
            public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.IBqlField
            {
            }
            protected Int32? _InventoryID;
            [CrossItem(INPrimaryAlternateType.CPN, Filterable = true)]
            public virtual Int32? InventoryID
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._InventoryID;
                }
                set
                {
                    this._InventoryID = value;
                }
            }
            #endregion
```

**EDIT**

Tried to use as an unbound field

```
        #region InvID
        public abstract class invID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        [PXInt]        
        [CrossItem(DisplayName="TEST")]
        public virtual int? InvID { get; set; }
        #endregion InvID
```

**Item master info**
[image]

**Unbound field, Keys in the barcode**

[image]

**System Finds the correct Item**

[image]

Comment: I tried appending CrossItemAttribute Item to inventoryID, but while publishing I got this error. 

http://www.screencast.com/t/lVJZ9rlS

By the way, I tried to look for the documentation on this attribute, but couldn't find. I looked on help.acumatica.com and even went through available pdf files but couldn't find anywhere and google search didn't help too.

Comment: please add your inventory ID DAC field in the question. Cross item attribute is in namespace PX.Objects.IN. Also i see that you specified the bql field in your screen shot which is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't understand your answer. But this is the page where I am trying to customize. http://www.screencast.com/t/SJ7evdHdpQ3
And here is the change I have put. But see no differnce.
http://www.screencast.com/users/bikash_sbpk/folders/Default/media/65231beb-09ab-444a-b946-2f6e44d15058

Comment: is this a custom screen? can you try to change the customize attributes: Replace Original

Comment: Yes. This 'Appointments' page is from another custom project called 'Service Management'. Could you please elaborate 'Replace original'?

Comment: You dont have the code for that custom project?
in your screen shot http://www.screencast.com/users/bikash_sbpk/folders/Default/media/65231beb-09ab-444a-b946-2f6e44d15058 you can see customize attributes. try to Use 'Replace Original' there instead of 'Append original'

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work even using 'Replace Original'.
http://www.screencast.com/t/szUwBe1WU
http://www.screencast.com/t/vxgG6l6Ok
Still says invalid inventory ID.

Comment: the value you are entering is customer part number? what is the type of alternate id? you have to mention it correctly in the attribute

Comment: It is actually a concatenated string form of cross reference of stock item which I have stored in a custom database field.
http://www.screencast.com/t/ht7sy5hcWta
And its data type is string.
I don't what its INPrimaryAlternateType would be. Sorry, I am yet to be fully familiarized with acumatica terms. Please tell me if still infos are missing. Thanks.

Comment: Acumatica item screen have a Cross reference tab, and i believe, you are trying to search information using that. am i right? if yes, what is the type of alternate ID you are searching for? Dont care about your custom field.

Comment: Actually, I have already done that. I can search for inventory using cross reference value with the help of custom field alternateid using inventory id selector. What I required now is, (let's not care about custom field.), user should be able to put any alternate id from cross reference of inventory item, and it should select the product and put product id in the field itself.

Comment: "user should be able to put any alternate id from cross reference of inventory item, and it should select the product and put product id in the field itself"
this is what the above attribute do. But you are not answering the question what is the type of "alternate id". May be you should learn a bit more about acumatica or else we keep commenting here. hehe.

Comment: I think, I got your question. The type of alternate id is Barcode. https://www.screencast.com/t/CnV8C4uiL8At

Comment: so use accordingly, i have mentioned that in answer.  I think you can use without that like [CrossItem()]

 "INPrimaryAlternateType.CPN defines the type of alternate id"

Comment: Sorry for asking again and again. I am unable to find option for INPrimaryAlternateType, the only two options are CPN(Customer Part Number) and VPN(Vendor Part Number). I didn't see option for Global and Barcode.
http://www.screencast.com/t/GqUGoLb7k
And, I don't think I can use without [CrossItem()] if I am applying an attribute to that field property.

Comment: Did you try? because i saw the implementation of that attribute, it searches for barcode when the INPrimaryAlternateType is not mentioned.

Comment: Yeah. I had tried even before adding attribute to the property.

Comment: so you are saying,  [CrossItem()] this is not working?

Comment: Sadly, yes. I tried all the ways you have asked me to do. But none of these work.

Comment: sorry to know that its not working for you, i have confirmed that it is working. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi! It looks like I was reading your answer in different way. After your new answer, I tried this and it worked. I only had to do this.
http://www.screencast.com/t/mcbMOfmxSp6

Thank you so much bearing with as I am still novice to this.

Comment: When I try to search inventory in mobile using cross reference value, it is unable to find.
http://www.screencast.com/t/dIIpgvR9f
http://www.screencast.com/t/XAsZ3nkxlsk

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't try this with mobile.

Comment: Ok. Is there anything I can do to make this work in mobile too?